# "Cohomology at the infinity": what does one call it

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, cohomology

Suppose $X$ is a "good enough" Hausdorff topological space; we assume that $X$ is *not* compact. Now, for a natural number $k$ and an abelian group $G$, consider the group $\varinjlim_{\substack{U\subseteq X\\ \text{$X\setminus U$ is compact}}} H^k(U,G)$.

Could you, please, give me a reference to a text where this object is defined? I would like to learn the standard term and notation for it.

Thank you in advance,
Serge

Comment: I think this is called 'cohomology of ends'. It is used by Geoghegan in 'Topological Methods in Group Theory', see 3.8 (numbering of the preprint version). I first learned about this somewhere else, but I don't remember the title of the book, nor the author.

Comment: I think the following link is relevant: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/95974/proofs-of-the-stallings-swan-theorem

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is the *cohomology of $X$ at $\infty$*. You'll find a discussion of (singular) homology and cohomology at $\infty$ in Hughes & Ranicki, [*Ends of Complexes*](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/books/ends.pdf) (CUP, 1996).

Comment: @Igor. Oh, so I even guessed the word:))) Thanks a lot for the answer and the reference.