# Generalized Stallings theorem

Tags: gr.group-theory, homological-algebra, homological-dimension

Well known theorem due to Stallings (finished by Swan) characterises free groups as those with $cd_{\mathbb Z} \leq 1$. We can treat it as a model case and try to extrapolate somehow to other categories and homological (feel free to interprete this adjective ad lib) functors — can we characterise free objects as "1-dimensional" ones? Here are some examples with different outcomes.

- groups, homological dimension — yes for finitely presented (by duality), false for arbitrary ($\mathbb Q$), open for finitely generated
- Lie algebras, Chevalley cohomology — yes for 2-generated (Feldman, 1983), no for char $\geq$ 3 (Mikhalev, 90s), open otherwise
- restricted Lie algebras, Chevalley cohomology — sort of, the only example is 1-dimensional vector space (Zusmanovich, 2010s)
- restricted Lie algebras, restricted cohomology ($HH^*$ of univ. p-enveloping) — 0-dimensional are finite dimensional tori (exercise in Weibel's book), conjectured by Zusmanovich that any 1-dimensional has solvable series with 1 free factor and arbitrary number of tori
- associative algebras, Hochschild cohomolology — measures different property (formal smoothness), same story but somewhat different details for commutative case

Finally, a few questions.

1. Are there some other interesting categories with "Stallings" property? (I'm particularly interested in the case of (pre)crossed modules with something like triple cohomology — which is not very good for intended purpose, but everything goes.)
2. Can we fit this zoo in a unified framework?
3. Back to beginning — every proof of Stallings' thm I'm avare of is geometric or combinatorial in nature and usually relies on Grushko rank theorem which is again an essentially combinatorial statement. Is there a purely homological one?

Comment: Re the last question: Gromov gave  a non-combinatorial proof (details checked by Kapovich https://arxiv.org/pdf/0707.4231.pdf), but it uses harmonic functions ...

Comment: Novikov showed a cancellative monoid of cohomological dimension one embeds in a free group. In general cohomological dimension one says nothing.

Answer (score 1):

A finite dimensional algebra has global dimension one if and only if it is Morita equivalent to a path algebra of an acyclic quiver by Gabriel's theorem. A path algebra is just the algebra of a free category on the quiver.

Comment: Nice! But free category on a quiver is very far from being as *free* as a free group, because Cat and Quiv are very similar, unlike Grp and Set. In my opinion, this result is closer to nonexistence of 1-dimensional p-Lie algebras than to "Stallings-y" ones — in a sense, gd is too restrictive.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a comment than an answer, but the question is closely related to [this question.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/95974/proofs-of-the-stallings-swan-theorem) Particularly relevant to your question is John Klein's answer, and even more specifically, the second part, where he discusses Daniel Cohen's Lecture notes (with pointers to more algebraic approaches).